# Returning dynamic/generic object or POCO

Tags: c#, .net, rest, asp.net-web-api

So when I am writing a Web API I was thinking how to handle a situation when an error occurs.  How should I inform the consumer what happened and how to correct it.  I have an error object that I would return things such as an error number, message, possible causes and solution when the consumer violates a business rule.  My immediate thought is to return the POCO and return the error object when an error gas occurred, but this means every controller would have to return a generic object to allow this.  It just seems to be a violation of a contract or some programming principle. I mean ultimately it will always result in an JSON object but for the controller to return "object" seems so vague

Comment: I don't know if your API is restful, but if so, you could build an httpResponse (and use the http return codes).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning the POCO object or the Error object as a 'generic' object, return a new class using C# Generics:

```
public class Response<T>
{
    public T Value { get; set; }
    public ErrorClass Error { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Is there any benefit to me using a generic over returning a dynamic object?  Isn't it essentially the same?  I kind of what I want to say: the return type for this action is ..... unless there was a problem then you will receive an error object, in which case you will receive the object back wrapped encapsulated in the error object. so that if a user calls .../product/create/ they can expect a product object.  I guess it is rather moot since it will get serialized anyway.  Also, is it good programming technique to have all the return type be the same wrapper object?